# Classification of Day time in R for predictive analysis

Tags: r, datetime, predict

I have a time column in my data that looks like this:

```
   9:41:12 AM  7:13:00 PM  4:15:54 PM  1:40:49 PM  12:52:37 PM 3:18:11 PM  5:00:02 PM  7:12:25 PM  5:34:47 PM  9:03:39 AM 
 1:00:01 PM 1:00:16 PM 1:00:22 PM 1:00:41 PM 1:00:47 PM 1:00:53 PM 1:01:45 PM 1:01:54 PM 1:02:40 PM
```

I'm trying to create a target column for multinomial regression model in predictive analysis such that I can put the time ranges in different buckets.

An example of my attempt is given below:

```
ifelse(df$time > 10:00 AM & df$time < 1:00 PM, 1,
 ifelse(df$time >= 1:00 PM & df$time < 10:00 PM, 2, NA))
```

It gives an error of unexpected symbol.

I looked at [R: Seperating out a mixed data column, date above multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169485/r-seperating-out-a-mixed-data-column-date-above-multiple-times) but it did not solve my problem.

Please help.

Edit:

Sample of dput:

```
structure(c(2630L, 1973L, 1560L, 183L, 1100L, 1419L, 1674L, 
1971L), .Label = c("1:00:01 PM", "1:00:16 PM", "1:00:22 PM", "1:00:41 PM",
"1:00:47 PM", "1:00:53 PM", "1:01:45 PM", "1:01:54 PM"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: can you please show the results of dput on your df object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's how you've entered the time in both your data and in the comparison.

Dates need to be in the proper format (you left out the seconds) and as quoted strings in the comparison.

Also you need to make sure it's stored in a proper class and not as character.

```
a <- c("9:41:12 AM", "9:41:12 PM")
class(a) # Can't use character data the way you want to

a <- data.frame(a=a,flag=NA) # Flag will indicate AM / PM
a$flag <- grepl(" AM",a$a)

require(lubridate)     # lubridate makes working with time fun and easy
a$a <- hms(a$a)        # give it a proper class
a$a[a$flag == F] <- a$a[a$flag == F] + hms("12:00:00") # add 12 hours if it's PM
a
```

> ```
>    a           flag
> 1  9H 41M 12S  TRUE
> 2 21H 41M 12S FALSE
> ```

```
# Now let's do a comparison:
hms("12:00:00") > a$a #works
```

> [1]  TRUE FALSE

Comment: thanks for the highlights, very useful. Now coming to the comparison. I did `a$b = ifelse(a$a < '10H 00M 00S', 1, ifelse(a$a > '10H 00M 00S', 2,NA))`  with output `[1] 2 2` while I was expecting the result `[1] 1 2`. What do you think could be the issue?